# How do I generate a unique ID for a custom date picker model template?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have over-ridden the default Date template using the following edit template:

```
@model DateTime
@Html.TextBox("", Model.ToString("d"), 
 new { @class = "datepicker" })
```

..which generates:

```
<input class="datepicker" id="FromDate" name="FromDate" type="text" value="08/05/2013">
```

I then attach a jquery datepicker to all items with the class of 'datepicker'.

The issue I have is that the id of FromDate sometimes conflicts with other inputs on the same page, especially when this form is displayed modally.

I'm wondering if there is a useful strategy to generating some sort of unique prefix for the textbox that still allows mvc to bind the edited value back to 'FromDate' in my model?

Answer (score 0):

if it's coming from DB, it should have an identity value, if its there then you can use that id. other wise go for GUID.

using Guid.NewGuid() and concat with the id value.

```
@Html.TextBox("fromDate_"+Guid.NewGuid(), Model.ToString("d"),  new { @class = "datepicker" })
```

Comment: The problem is, the property name from the model is used to name the textbox so need to get what that is and append a unique ID. So when the property is "FromDate" I will generate "FromDate" + GUID but if the property name is "ToDate" I generate "ToDate" + GUID. How would I get the name of the property from within the template?